# Kendo UI numeric text box value based on Grid row selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am able to extract the desired value from selected row in the kendo ui grid but I am unable to refresh the numeric text box value based on that selection. Here is my code to set the value:

```
    function OnChangeDivTimberGradeGrid(arg) {
        var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
            var grade = $(item).text().substring(0, 3);
            alert(grade);
            var numerictextbox = $("#TimberGrade").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
            numerictextbox.value(grade);

        });
    }
```

and here is how I define the numeric text box.

```
<p>Timber Grade =  @(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(x => x.TimberGrade)
    .Name("TimberGrade")
    .Value("C16")
) 
</p>
```

Comment: Can you check the textbox has the ID of "TimberGrade" in HTML, and if you're getting any errors in the console? I'm guessing grade is being alerted fine, so it's the last two lines which is proving issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#TimberGrade").val(grade);
```

edit:

```
var numerictextbox = $("#TimberGrade").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

is not correct. the data portion is off. It should be

```
$("#TimberGrade").data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

First you must clear the value, then you can set it.

```
$("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(""); 
$("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(grade);
```

I think that will work